# Strange behaviour with mktime producing error in June/July

Tags: php, mktime

I have the following ungainly code to turn a date string into another date string.

```
//$invDate starts as a date string in format dd/mm/yyyy
$dateArray = explode('/', $invDate);      
$invDate = $dateArray[0] .' '.  date("F",mktime (1,1,1,$dateArray[1])) .' '. $dateArray[2];
```

I'm not particularly proud of it, but it produces an unambiguous date in a country where both US and UK methods of doing dates can produce confusion.

It's worked fine for ages, and then suddenly today it has started turning

```
01/06/2012
```

into

```
1 July 2012
```

I've looked at how mktime behaves, and can't see any reason why `mktime (1,1,1,6)` should ever produce a date in July. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that, pretty obviously I could create an array of months and not use mktime, but I'm interested to see if I've made a mistake, or it's a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) defaults to the current time for missing fields.  Since you didn't specify a day, and today is `May 31st` it is assuming `June 31`, which doesn't exist so it wraps around to July.  Specify a day by adding a fifth argument to mktime:

```
date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $dateArray[1], 1))
```